# How can I bring up 'bullet points' in a follow up letter?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I wrote a letter to a community council regarding a presentation I wish to make.  I am writing a follow-up letter asking if they have an interest in meeting in person.  (They indicated by phone that they did.)  I want to state in my second letter what the points are that I want to bring out at the face-to-face meeting.  How do I say that without saying "As a reminder, these are the benefits I feel my company can bring to your community"?  It's the "as a reminder" that I don't care for.  "I would like to point out that..." also seems like I think the readers are morons.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

I like using "to summarize" in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hesitant on using the phrase you can omit it entirely as the information itself should bring enough attention. If you feel the need for a phrase then try "To give an overview" or "I'd like to highlight" as neither sound too arrogant.